# Recursive Definitions for Theorems

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I recently encountered with the statement "Recursive definition may be used to define not only sets but also to prove correctness of functions." and questioned on whether it is really true. We are usually using induction to prove some properties after recursive definitions, but this seems to be somehow incorrect. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: It would help to say exactly where (web page, book and page number, journal paper and page number, etc.) you saw this. For example, "prove correctness of functions" makes no sense (like saying "correctness of the Earth"). I suspect you mean what is usually stated as "prove the function is well defined", but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro For example, when we want to prove some property of given sequence. This sequence was defined by recursive definition, but questions asks to prove some property

Comment: Or, say we define recursive definitions for strings, and how reverse of it is constructed. Now, we are asked to prove a property related to that

Comment: It is mostly about proving correctness for recursively defined operation